# How can I create a list of elements that can't be next to each other based on constraint?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, constraints

I'm trying to solve a constraint satisfaction problem for a personal project and I can't seem to figure it out. I have to create a list from a given list of elements. Each element can be placed next to certain other elements. For example, let's say I have 5 elements and the following constraints:

```
1: {3, 5}
2: {3, 4}
3: {1, 2}
4: {2, 5}
5: {1, 4}
```

so 1 can only be placed next to 3 and 5, 2 can only be placed next to 3 and 4 etc. I have to find an efficient way to solve the problem with no conflicts. I tried to start with the most "pretentious" element (the one who has the shortest list of elements it can be placed next to), but the algorithm fails to find a solution with no conflicts. Also, I have thought about using backtracking but it sounds like it would take too long to execute. Keep in mind that the size of the initial list of elements can be very big and that the algorithm has to find a solution in less than 2.5 minutes.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As some fodder for research, your problem is equivalent to finding a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) on an undirected graph.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Brian! I thought about this too, but the problem is that when we get to a node whose neighbors are all visited the algorithm blocks. So there's still some nodes that we haven't visited, but we can't reach them.

Comment: Potentially this problem is even a Hamiltonian _cycle_, if the resulting list is circular (_i.e._ the constraints wrap from the tail to the head of the list) or if only a subset of nodes are allowed to be at the head or tail (in which case there would be an additional "edge" node where the cycle must begin).  Regarding "reaching a node whose neighbors are all visited" then your algorithm is either broken or no solution is possible.

Comment: By quick inspection, 13245 is a valid path for your example (which also happens to be cyclic), so if your algorithm is terminating before reaching that, there's a problem with your implementation.